# How to perform DOM manipulation using pyscript

Tags: dom, pyscript

I understand that pyscript can be used as a client side scripting language.
Is there a way to interact with the DOM by using CSS selectors, similar to what you can do in JavaScript.

Something like :

```
nav_bar = get_element(".nav-bar")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can call JavaScript functions and access globals from Python. Import the js namespace:

```
import js
```

or

```
from js import document
```

Then you can call functions like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="msg">Loading page ...</div>

  <py-script>
from js import document

msg = document.getElementById("msg")
msg.innerHTML = 'Hello world'
  </pyscript>
</body>
```

The function `get_element()` is not a standard JavaScript function. It is a function located in libraries such as Telerik. Normally you can call those functions from Python provided they are not doing something special with namespaces and the library is loaded before PyScript. You can use normal JavaScript functions from Python to set CSS styles such as:

```
document.getElementById("msg").style.color = "blue"
```