# How to clear a terminal in pyscript (py-terminal)

Tags: python, web-frontend, pyscript

The idea is to clear the output of the python REPL provided by pyscript, embedded in a website.

I have tried the [regular ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console) used in the OS console (`os.system("clear")`, `print("\033c")` and similar), but they don't work.

I have not found anything in the documentation of the [py-repl](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-repl.html) or [py-terminal](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/plugins/py-terminal.html) elements.

Comment: Can you just grab the containing dom element, and set it to `""`?

Comment: Do you mean by using the inspector? That would work for me as a single user, but not for a product I want to offer to others (specially people that don't necessarily know how to use the inspector)

Comment: I meant by using javascript/pyscript and something like `document.getElementByID`, to grab the actual DOM node that pyscript is in, then clearing it.  You could actually delete the node, then re-insert it at the same point.

Comment: I guess that could make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to implement a function in python that uses the `js` module provided by pyscript to modify the DOM (see [How to perform DOM manipulation using pyscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515182/how-to-perform-dom-manipulation-using-pyscript)).

So a simplified version of my solution would look like this:

```html
<py-script>
from js import document as _DOC
def clear():
  ter = _DOC.getElementById("my-terminal")
  ter.innerHTML = ''
</py-script>
```

Put this code before your REPL and now you can execute the `clear()` function from it and the terminal will be cleared.